# Is there an Artinian ring with exactly two prime ideals which their product is non-zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is there an Artinian ring with exactly two prime ideals which their product is non-zero? Clearly these prime ideals could not be zero on the other hand the summation of them is equal to R.

Comment: Your example is a Artinian ring with exactly to prime ideal $2\mathbb Z$ and $3\mathbb Z$, however their product is zero ($6\mathbb Z$), which is does not work.

Comment: Is your ring commutative? If yes, you may choose the "commutative algebra" tag.

Comment: Doesn't matter suppose is commutative with identity.

Answer (score 6):

If $A,B$ are two local artinian rings which are not fields, then $A \times B$ provides an example. The two prime ideals are $\mathfrak{m}_A \times B$ and $A \times \mathfrak{m}_B$ and their product is $\mathfrak{m}_A \times \mathfrak{m}_B \neq 0$.

Comment: @MSSHD Yes, you've understood correctly. If you want a concrete $A$ and $B$ for this example, just use $A=B=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. And you can leverage it again to make an example that isn't commutative by using $A=B=M_2(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)$, and everything still holds (except $A,B$ aren't local anymore). It is a very flexible strategy!

Comment: Dear Martin Thanks for your help.